# Python Requests logging to file

Tags: python-requests

How can I configure logging to file requests's get or post?

```
my_config = {'verbose': sys.stderr}
requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', config=my_config)
```

What should I use in verbose?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply opening a file?

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys.stderr)
file
>>> f = open('test.log', 'w')
>>> type(f)
f
```

So the example above will look like this:

```
my_config = { 'verbose': open('/path/to/file', 'w') }
requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', config = my_config)
```

HTH